# Finding uncertainty with rounding

Tags: javascript, rounding, rounding-error

I'm a high school student in physics and I'm trying to write a code that finds uncertainty and rounds. I got the part that finds uncertainty but I'm struggling to get the code to round for me because it either just doesn't work or it rounds to 0 when it deals with small numbers can anyone help me? I've been trying to find a code on here that might help me but any code i tried form here didn't work for me.

Comment: Please provide the code tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
function roundHundredths (num) { 
  return Math.round(num * 100) / 100; 
}

console.log(roundHundredths(1.225)); // 1.23
console.log(roundHundredths(0.2));   // 0.2
console.log(roundHundredths(5.0));   // 5
```

Just increase the number of `0`s that you're multiplying and dividing by to get more or less precise, respectively.

Ex:

```js
function roundTenths (num) { 
  return Math.round(num * 10) / 10; 
}

console.log(roundTenths(1.225)); // 1.2
```

Comment: Thank you!! That helped a lot!!